# Морфемный разбор

Tags: суффиксы

В прилагательном "ослепительный" составной суффикс -тельн- или -тель-н-?Как он выделяется ,двумя значками или одним?Или это два разных суффикса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё Вы правильно выделили. Во всяком случае, это не ошибка. Дело в том, что, как Вы сами сказали, это составной суффикс. Когда-то его обозначали как рядом стоящие отдельные, но тогда, видимо, было и сущ. ослепитель, сейчас оно не употребляется. Остаётся цепочка слепой - слепить - ослепить - ослепительный. Суфф -тельн- принимается многими лингвистами:

Вот, например:

§ 652. Суффикс -тельн-. Прилагательные с суф. -тельн-/-ительн- (фонемат. |т'1л'н|/ |ит'1л'н|; перед |н| беглая |1|) имеют значение "характеризующийся отношением к действию, названному мотивирующим словом". http://rusgram.narod.ru/646-682.html

Покажите ей школьный словарь строения слов Потихи, там  так: `о/слеп/и/тельн/ый`

Answer (score 1):

Суффикс ТЕЛЬН используется при образовании прилагательных от глаголов: ослепить - ослепительный, измерить - измерительный,  наблюдать - наблюдательный.

Суффикс ИТЕЛЬН используется при образовании прилагательных от имен существительных глагольного происхождения  на -ЕНИЕ: вступление - вступительный, впечатление - впечатлительный.

Comment: Я обозначил -ТЕЛЬН- целым суффиксом,но препод-ль разбила его на два суффикса.

Comment: Если выделить отдельно суффикс Н, то мы получим схему: ослепитель - ослепительный. (Существовало ли это слово когда-либо или нет - значения не имеет). Если схема: ослепить - ослепительный, то получится, что мы используем два суффикса ТЕЛЬ+Н. Но это не два суффикса, а формант (составной суффикс), состоящий из двух элементарных суффиксов. Если это не признавать, то, к примеру, в словах "дружинник, поленница" мы аналогично не можем выделить суффиксы НИК, НИЦ,

Comment: Vera,где это Вы про -ительн такое вычитали?И впечатлительный, и впечатление - от глагола впечатлять. Морф -тельн используется после гласных основы, -ительн после согласных (в той же ссылке в ответе):а) в прилагательных, мотивированных глаголами Х кл. с  основой инф. -е-,  повелеть - повелительный, б) при мотивирующих глаг. VI и VII кл. с основой на согласную: спасти - спасительный, в) в  словах, мотивированных глаголами I и II кл. с отсекаемой финалью инф. основы -а- и -ова-: общаться - общительный,(§ 211).

Comment: Сведения из Толкового словаря словообразовательных единиц" Ефремовой. Впечатлительный - пассивная форма, это не тот, который сам может впечатлять, а тот, который склонен к получению впечатлений (легко и живо поддающийся впечатлениям, очень восприимчивый).